# Проблема с добавлением Resource Dictionary в WPF

Tags: wpf, resources

Имеется унаследованное приложение, разработанное на WPF. Проектов в приложении много, в том числе несколько проектов UI. Проблема в том, что в одном из этих UI проектов в контекстном меню нет опции Add/Resource Dictionary... Сравниваю два "соседних" проекта - в одном есть эта опция, в другом нет, хотя на первый оба одинаковы и ссылки на библиотеки тоже у них одинаковые.

Кстати, в этом же проекте в контекстном меню отсутствует опция Design in Blend...

Работаю с Visaul Studio 2015 Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы создавали проект не как WPF-проект. Разница в том, какие значения `ProjectTypeGuid` добавлены в проект.

Для того, чтобы исправить, закройте Visual Studio, откройте файл с проектом (`.csproj`) в текстовом редакторе, найдите тег `ProjectTypeGuids`, и убедитесь, что он выглядит так:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Кроме этого, вам нужны ссылки на `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework` и `WindowsBase`, но они, судя по всему, у вас уже есть.

Comment: у меня такая же беда  в старом WPF проекте где есть созданные словари. А добавить новый не могу, приходится копировать готовый из этого же проекта. Скорее всего дело в апдейте студии.

Comment: @vitidev: А рецепт из ответа не помогает?

Comment: Ну в ехе приложениях такое поле есть, а для dll что делать?

Comment: @vitidev: Добавить поле, если его нету?

Comment: Вроде помогло. Логика однако у разработчиков студии ) вернее ее отсутствие

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, что поделать? :)

Comment: А мне не помогло. При загрузке проекта получил вот такое сообщение об ошибке

error  : The element <ProjectTypeGuids> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.

Видимо придется пересоздавать проект.

Не я создавал проект, приложение унаследованное. Там вообще кошмар в коде и в архитектуре твориться.

Comment: @S_Schmal: Ну так значит вы не туда добавили. Посмотрите, где именно в «хорошем» `.csproj` лежит это, и добавьте в то же место.

Comment: Супер. Все работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @S_Schmal: Пожалуйста!