# C# - Создание WPF окна в dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

Можно ли создать dll с функцией (в каком-то классе), которая строит WPF окно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно!

Вы точно так же можете из любой функции создать окно:

```
var window = new MyWindow();
window.Show();
```

Не забудьте подключить сборки `PresesntationCore`, `PresentationFramework` и `WindowsBase`, а в свежей версии ещё и `System.Xaml`. И вы можете точно так же определить класс с окном в DLL, как и в основном приложении, через XAML.

Если у вас не получается добавить XAML для окна, вам понадобится вручную отредактировать csproj, как указано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526256/10105).

---

Если вы не в UI-потоке, и у вас WPF-приложение, вам придётся перебросить выполнение туда. Например, так:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
    { 
        var window = new MyWindow();
        window.Show();
    });
```

---

Если у вас консольное приложение, всё немного сложнее, т. к. у вас нету UI-потока. Вам нужно его создать. Как это делать, написано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541723/10105).

Вот рабочий пример:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var window = new MyWindow();
    window.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49426/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-c-wpf---dll).